# Problem of URLs with internal links with 'base href'

Tags: html, links, relative-urls

I've got a website with includes the following directive in the HEAD section:

```
<base href="https://example.com" />
```

Now, I want to create internal links to sections within the page 'https://foo.com/product/name-of-the-product'

```
<a href="#photos">Photos</a>
```

But, instead of linking to 'https://foo.com/product/name-of-the-product#photos', it links to 'https://foo.com/#photos'.

Any tip to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you remove the base href?   Technically it isn't a problem.  That is how base href is supposed to work.   It sounds like you don't actually want a base href.

Answer (score 2):

I can't recall ever having tried it but I'm oddly certain you can use

"/name-of-the-product#photos" instead of just #photos

Alternatively, as @StephenOstermiller says, drop the "base" statement from the header (you can likely replace its functionality with RewriteRules at the server config level or similar if you are trying to create a canonical URL.

Comment: Can you imbed php code in your page? If so you can use php to programmatically deduce name-of-product", eg <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>